# Al correr codigo en segundo plano y salir de la app no se ejecuta la funcion turnOffSystem. Saben a que se debe?

Tags: flutter, dart, programación-móvil

El siguiente codigo funciona bien incluso cambiando de pantalla:
pero falla o no ejecuta la funcion turnOffSystem al salir de la app
The following code works fine even when changing screens:
but it fails or does not execute the turnOffSystem function when exiting the app

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';
import 'package:tesis_iot/connection_page.dart';
import 'package:tesis_iot/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

ConnectionBroker brokerObj = ConnectionBroker();
final isRiegoActive = ValueNotifier(false);
final numero1 = ValueNotifier(0);

class IrrigationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const IrrigationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  IrrigationPageState createState() => IrrigationPageState();
}

class IrrigationPageState extends State<IrrigationPage> {
  int selectedDuration = 1;
  MqttServerClient client = brokerObj.client;

  Future<void> connectionToBroker() async {
    brokerObj.connectToBroker();
  }

conexion con el broker o si no se está ejecutando en segundo plano esa parte
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectionToBroker();
    Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Riego App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
              valueListenable: isRiegoActive,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Switch(
                  value: value,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isRiegoActive.value = value;
                      if (value) {
                        turnOnSystem("/casa/foco", selectedDuration);
                      } else {
                        turnOffSystem("/casa/foco");
                      }
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
            DropdownButton<int>(
              value: selectedDuration,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedDuration = value!;
                  Workmanager().cancelAll();
                  Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
                    '1',
                    'mqttTask',
                    inputData: {'duration': selectedDuration.toString()},
                  );
                });
              },
              items: [1, 2, 5].map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((int value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text('$value minutes'),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Text(numero1.value.toString()),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  numero1.value++;
                });
              },
              child: const Text("sumar"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void turnOnSystem(String topic, int duration) async {
    final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString("ON");
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atMostOnce, builder.payload!);
    Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: duration), () {
      isRiegoActive.value = false;
      turnOffSystem("/casa/foco");
    });
  }

  void turnOffSystem(String topic) {
    final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString("OFF");
    client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atMostOnce, builder.payload!);
    mostrarNotificacion();
  }

  void callbackDispatcher() {
    Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
      String duration = inputData!['duration'];
      turnOnSystem("/casa/Foco", int.parse(duration));
      return Future.value(true);
    });
  }
}
```

No me muestra ningun error por la consola, no se si se debe a que se pierde la conexion con el broker o si no se está ejecutando en segundo plano esa parte

It doesn't show me any errors in the console, I don't know if it is because the connection with the broker is lost or if that part is not running in the background.

Comment: El idioma del sitio es el español, por lo tanto el inglés está demás. Por otra parte, tu código es Dart/Flutter, y no está soportado en los snippets. Dale el formato correspondiente agregando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del código. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Una vez la app se cierra la conexión con el broker se cierra también por lo cual lo mas seguro es que la task se ejecute pero no puede enviar los datos al broker.